# Internationalization for DateTime is not working

Tags: datetime, internationalization, flutter

I have a demo app and the Internationalization is not working correctly.
My time code is +3 (North Cyprus). Language is TR. Date part works for TR.
but time is not working. Example instead of showing 08:27:18 it shows 05:27.18 GMT time.

More info: https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/europe/turkey/

Examples: https://github.com/NTMS2017/Internationalization

Any help please?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Internationalization',
            theme: new ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Internationalization'),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    DateFormat dateFormat;
    DateFormat timeFormat;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initializeDateFormatting();
        dateFormat = new DateFormat.yMMMMd('tr_TR');
        timeFormat = new DateFormat.Hms('tr_TR');
    }

    void _refresh() {
        setState(() {});
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var dateTime = new DateTime.now();
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text(widget.title),
                backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            ),
            body: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(dateFormat.format(dateTime),
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                            ),
                        ),
                        new Text(timeFormat.format(dateTime),
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _refresh,
                tooltip: 'Refresh',
                child: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to the question instead of only linking to external resources.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks. I did it now.

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14128

Comment: Your code is working perfectly at my end.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. Thanks. It is working now. My Simulator is Nexus 5X API 26. Setting the simulator Language and Region is working now. This is the very basic configuration. But I couldn’t fin in Flutter documentation. Use of intl: ^0.15.6 must shows this configuration and make them better.

Comment: Please create an issue for that.

Answer (score 0):

With @GünterZöchbauer help. I check my android simulator.

My Simulator is Nexus 5X API 26. 
Setting the simulator Language to TR and Region to Turkey the above code works well.